# Where do I add the --scan parameter when running a Gradle project from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am a Gradle Rookie, I used Maven multiple years and switched because it seemed better after reading comments on it. I want to add the `--scan` parameter when running the project in IntelliJ for better overview. The thing is, that there is no such thing as "Scripting Parameters" as often described in other threads.

I tried multiple text boxes with no success.

Where can I add the `--scan` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this article

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html

In `Arguments` section you can append you parameter `--scan`

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for answering. The thing is I want a main method to start and include "--scan".

Comment: nvm. got it working. I was so dumb holy. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You can accept this as an answer if it solves your query.